# Unknown parser class "PropelArrayParser"

Tags: php, propel

I'm new to Propel and I need to work with a website that was already setup with Propel (1.6.9).
I got this working on my laptop and generated without any errors. (Yay!)

After generating classes (on the same schema.xml and other related files as earlier on) there seem to be some differences. (spotted in file sizes) When I uploaded these files to the web hosting where the old files were doing a fine job, I ran into an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message 'Unknown parser class "PropelArrayParser"' in /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/DOMAIN/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/parser/PropelParser.php:101 

Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/DOMAIN/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/om/BaseObject.php(375): PropelParser::getParser('Array') 
#1 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/DOMAIN/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/om/BaseObject.php(424): BaseObject->exportTo('Array', 'fieldName') 
#2 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/DOMAIN/src/controllers/UsersController.php(26): BaseObject->__call('toArray', Array) 
#3 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/DOMAIN/src/controllers/UsersController.php(26): User->toArray('fieldName') 
#4 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/DOMAIN/framework/framework.php(196): require('/var/www/vhosts...') 
#5 /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/web in /var/www/vhosts/10/154462/webspace/httpdocs/DOMAIN/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/parser/PropelParser.php on line 101
```

The error is referring to:

```
$case = new AgencyCosts();
$case->fromArray($_POST, BasePeer::TYPE_FIELDNAME);
$case->save();
```

So I figured something was wrong with includes. That's why I added the following to my init.php:

> set_include_path(dirname(**DIR**) . '/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/parser' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
>
> require dirname(**DIR**) . '/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/parser/PropelJSONParser.php';

Without any success.

The init.php (where the including is done) is available [here](http://pastebin.com/CmkVRc88).
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this exception when Propel cannot find the class definition. From Propel's code:

```
// PropelParse::getParser
if (!class_exists($class)) {
    throw new PropelException(sprintf('Unknown parser class "%s"', $class));
}
```

Propel generates a classmap file, where the paths of all Propel's classes are written. It seems like you just get the wrong file included or wrong paths in it. Take a look at your configuration file for the `classmap` key:

```
$conf['classmap'] = include(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classmap-<you-project-name>-conf.php');
```

And then examine the contents of that file. It might happen because you blindly moved the files from your computer to the server.